# Exception[Invalid parameter] when getting reach metrics of Media Posted Before Business Account Conversion

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, laravel-5.7

This is the case of Media Posted Before Business Account Conversion.
The issue is I'm getting correct response in Facebook graph api explorer.

```
"insights": {
        "data": [
          {
            "values": [
              {
                "value": 8
              }
            ],
            "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/insights/reach/lifetime"
          }
        ]
      },
```

But when trying using api call, `xxxxxxxxx/media?fields=media_url,caption,comments_count,permalink,media_type,like_count,timestamp,username,thumbnail_url,insights.metric(reach){values}` I'm getting

> dev.ERROR: Jobs >> FacebookInstagramBackTrackOwned >> Exception >>Invalid parameter.

```
'error_subcode' => 2108006,
'is_transient' => false,
'error_user_title' => 'Media Posted Before Business Account Conversion',
'error_user_msg' => 'The media was posted before the most recent time that the user\'s account was converted to a business account from a personal account.'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is in the catch exception part , i checked for error code, `2108006` and error_user_title, `Media Posted Before Business Account Conversion`.Then made call without reach parameter, so that I'm getting all other data.

Comment: Can you explain how you did it?